# Does universal link work on the apps from enterprise program?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I've followed instructions from the apple for enabling universal links.

Following is my aasa file

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "app.store.app",
                "paths": ["*"]
            },
            {
                "appID": "enterprise.app",
                "paths": ["*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am able to use universal link for the app store app. But I've never been able to open links for the enterprise app(apps that are created for internal distribution https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/)...

I have followed https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html and made sure that "The appID value is the same value that’s associated with the “application-identifier” key in your app’s entitlements after you build it". I have also check the entitlement file having the domain

Is there any document from Apple stating that enterprise apps cannot use universal link?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever root cause your issue? I am in the same situation, everything seems to be in order except when I install the enterprise build on devices the universal inks don't work. Even when I try to filter installation logs with `swcd` it looks like it isn't even trying to download it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YES**

In order to allow such a behavior, be sure to provide the apporiate TEAMID in the json file, as described https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/enabling_universal_links

```
"details": [{
            "appID": "D3KQX62K1A.com.example.photoapp",
            "paths": ["/albums"]
```

Moreover if your internal apps point to another server than the public one, remind to add a new `associated domain` in your app capabilities

Comment: I've followed https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html to implement but no luck for the enterprise app... I have made sure "The appID value is the same value that’s associated with the “application-identifier” key in your app’s entitlements after you build it" I also check that the domain is in the entitlement file

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to remove the the developer mode from the associated domain when you are going to distribute your application.
We had the issue that Universal Links didn't work for a distributed Enterprise Application.
Removing the developer mode fixed it.